# Downloading a maven artifact from GitHub Packages via Ansible

Tags: maven, ansible, github-package-registry

**Context**

I have *maven artifacts* deployed to *a private GitHub Packages Maven registry*. There are `snapshot` and `release` packages deployed to this registry.
The `snapshot` package for a specific version is recently updated. This results in multiple packages with a different timestamp being deployed to the same version (e.g. `artifact-0.0.1-20220524.045831-5.jar` and `artifact-0.0.1-20220523.122646-4.jar`).

**Goal**

I now would like to be able to fetch the **latest** packages for this specific version with *Ansible*. To do that, I currently use the [maven_artifact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/maven_artifact_module.html) Ansible module. I am able to download an artifact, but I always receive the first artifact which has been deployed to that version (the one with the oldest timestamp). Instead, I would like to receive the **latest version**.

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone know why I do not get the latest but the oldest version?
2. Is there a way to achieve that with Ansible?

---

**My Ansible task**

```
- name: download maven artifact
  maven_artifact:
    artifact_id: artifact
    group_id: group.id
    version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    repository_url: https://maven.pkg.github.com/org/repo
    extension: jar
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ token }}"
    dest: /home/path
```

Comment: does the `/metadata/versioning/snapshot` element in `maven-metadata.xml` matches your expectations?

Comment: I accessed that via this URL: https://maven.pkg.github.com/org/repo/group.id/artifact/maven-metadata.xml 
It only shows 3 versions under /metadata/versioning/versions. One of it being my 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. And a lastUpadated timestamp under /metadata/versioning which seems to be the last time we pushed to any version. 

I don't know, how it should look like to be honest. It has no .../snapshot attribute in the XML. Could it be, that it treats my 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT as normal version (not snapshot)?

Comment: Ah, I checked out this other URL (where also mvn dependency:get would  pull from): https://maven.pkg.github.com/org/repo/group/id/artifact/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

This one shows the latest version in the /metadata/versioning/snapshot attribute in the XML. Meaning that this looks correct.

mvn dependency:get also gets the latest snapshot version. That means, that your hint, that there might be a problem with the Ansible module, makes sense.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to your problem? I bumped into the same issue and the bug you reported is still open. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, no solution to that yet. I did not follow it further.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe the root cause of your problem is the implementation of [maven_artifact.py](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/packaging/language/maven_artifact.py#L464):

```py
for snapshotArtifact in xml.xpath("/metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions/snapshotVersion"):
    classifier = snapshotArtifact.xpath("classifier/text()")
    artifact_classifier = classifier[0] if classifier else ''
    extension = snapshotArtifact.xpath("extension/text()")
    artifact_extension = extension[0] if extension else ''
    if artifact_classifier == artifact.classifier and artifact_extension == artifact.extension:
        return self._uri_for_artifact(artifact, snapshotArtifact.xpath("value/text()")[0])
timestamp_xmlpath = xml.xpath("/metadata/versioning/snapshot/timestamp/text()")
if timestamp_xmlpath:
    timestamp = timestamp_xmlpath[0]
    build_number = xml.xpath("/metadata/versioning/snapshot/buildNumber/text()")[0]
    return self._uri_for_artifact(artifact, artifact.version.replace("SNAPSHOT", timestamp + "-" + build_number))
```

in case of [real-world example](https://repository.apache.org/service/local/repo_groups/snapshots-group/content/org/apache/commons/commons-cli/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml):

```xml
<versioning>
    <snapshot>
        <timestamp>20110801.092600</timestamp>
        <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20110802070230</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.3-20100616.143343-1</value>
            <updated>20100616143343</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.3-20100616.143343-1</value>
            <updated>20100616143343</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.3-20110801.092600-2</value>
            <updated>20110801092600</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>pom</extension>
            <value>1.3-20110801.092600-2</value>
            <updated>20110801092600</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
</versioning>
```

it traverse xml in wrong order: at first it checks `versioning/versioning` elements (`for snapshotArtifact in...`) and after that it checks `versioning/snapshot` element (`timestamp_xmlpath = xml.xpath...`)

Comment: Looking at the code and the fact, that it works without Ansible, this sounds reasonable. I created a GitHub issue in their repo here: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/5117

Will wait for an answer and then probably accept this answer. 

Thanks for your quick help.